# Descending Filtering for Dataframe

Tags: python, for-loop, dataframe, if-statement, filter

I have a dataframe such as

```
Index   Results  Price
0       Buy      10
1       Sell     11
2       Buy      12
3       Neutral  13
4       Buy      14
5       Sell     15
```

I would like to ultimately return the price difference for the first continuous combination of Buy and then Sell Results in a descending manner. Such that the first output is a difference of 1, second output 3.

```
for buy in df: 
        if buy:
              df['Buy Price'] = df['Price']
           for sell in df:
                  if sell:
                      df['Sell Price'] = df['Price']
                      df['Difference'] = df['Sell Price'] - df['Buy Price']
```

Desired Output

```
Index Results Price Difference
0     Buy     10    
1     Sell    11    1
2     Buy     12    
3     Neutral 13    
4     Buy     14    
5     Sell    15    3
```

I have attempted to implement a counter but with no such luck. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a manual loop with a couple of Boolean flags. Here I use `numba` to add some element of optimisation:

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def get_diffs(results, prices):
    res = np.full(prices.shape, np.nan)
    prev_one, prev_zero = True, False
    for i in range(len(results)):
        if prev_one and (results[i] == 0):
            price_start = prices[i]
            prev_zero, prev_one = True, False
        elif prev_zero and (results[i] == 1):
            res[i] = prices[i] - price_start
            prev_zero, prev_one = False, True
    return res

results = df['Results'].map({'Buy': 0, 'Sell': 1})

df['Difference'] = get_diffs(results.values, df['Price'].values)

print(df)

   Index  Results  Price  Difference
0      0      Buy     10         NaN
1      1     Sell     11         1.0
2      2      Buy     12         NaN
3      3  Neutral     13         NaN
4      4      Buy     14         NaN
5      5     Sell     15         3.0
```

Comment: ah this work beautifully, made some silly errors by not copy pasting your entire code block.

Comment: ah I see your edit, very nice addition to rule out multiple "sell" from results. Thank you jpp

Comment: @moader808, Potentially better answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52731648/9209546) for you :)