# Vectorising a loop based on the order of values in a series

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy, dataframe

This question is based on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730234/descending-filtering-for-dataframe) I answered.

The input looks like:

```
Index   Results  Price
0       Buy      10
1       Sell     11
2       Buy      12
3       Neutral  13
4       Buy      14
5       Sell     15
```

I need to find every Buy-Sell sequence (ignoring extra Buy / Sell values out of sequence) and calculate the difference in Price.

The desired output:

```
Index Results Price Difference
0     Buy     10    
1     Sell    11    1
2     Buy     12    
3     Neutral 13    
4     Buy     14    
5     Sell    15    3
```

My solution is verbose but seems to work:

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def get_diffs(results, prices):
    res = np.full(prices.shape, np.nan)
    prev_one, prev_zero = True, False
    for i in range(len(results)):
        if prev_one and (results[i] == 0):
            price_start = prices[i]
            prev_zero, prev_one = True, False
        elif prev_zero and (results[i] == 1):
            res[i] = prices[i] - price_start
            prev_zero, prev_one = False, True
    return res

results = df['Results'].map({'Buy': 0, 'Sell': 1})

df['Difference'] = get_diffs(results.values, df['Price'].values)
```

Is there a vectorised method? I'm concerned about code maintainability and performance over a large number of rows.

---

**Edit:** Benchmarking code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Index': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5},
                             'Results': {0: 'Buy', 1: 'Sell', 2: 'Buy', 3: 'Neutral', 4: 'Buy', 5: 'Sell'},
                             'Price': {0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 13, 4: 14, 5: 15}})

df = pd.concat([df]*10**4, ignore_index=True)

def jpp(df):
    results = df['Results'].map({'Buy': 0, 'Sell': 1})    
    return get_diffs(results.values, df['Price'].values)

%timeit jpp(df)  # 7.99 ms ± 142 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll write up some alternatives using scipy and numpy later, but here's a clear, straightforward answer just to propose a vectorized alternative, although this will still fall behind `numba` in terms of performance.

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, a "Buy" will appear, followed by any number of possible alternatives, then finally a "Sell" will appear, and you want to find the difference between the first "Buy" and the "Sell".  Then another "Buy" will start, etc.

---

You can create a Series to group with using `cumsum` and `shift`:

```
a = df.Results.shift().eq('Sell').cumsum()
```

```
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
Name: Results, dtype: int32
```

You can next find the first and last values per group using `agg`:

```
agr = df.groupby(a).Price.agg(['first', 'last'])
```

Finally, we can assign to a new column using `loc`:

```
df.loc[df.Results.eq('Sell'), 'Diff'] = agr['last'].sub(agr['first']).values
```

```
   Index  Results  Price  Diff
0      0      Buy     10   NaN
1      1     Sell     11   1.0
2      2      Buy     12   NaN
3      3  Neutral     13   NaN
4      4      Buy     14   NaN
5      5     Sell     15   3.0
```

---

***Performance***

```
In [27]: df = pd.concat([df]*10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [28]: %%timeit
    ...: a = df.Results.shift().eq('Sell').cumsum()
    ...: agr = df.groupby(a).Price.agg(['first', 'last'])
    ...: df.loc[df.Results.eq('Sell'), 'Diff'] = agr['last'].sub(agr['first']).values
    ...:
17.6 ms ± 199 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [29]: %%timeit
    ...: s=df.groupby('Results').cumcount()
    ...: df['Diff']=df.Price.groupby(s).diff().loc[df.Results.isin(['Buy','Sell'])]
    ...:
3.71 s ± 331 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I can't actually run your code, I get a `TypingError`, so I can't compare.

Comment: Comment on the input. Buys and Sells can be anywhere. We're only interested in the Buy-Sell-Buy-Sell-Buy-Sell-etc... sequences without skipping any viable combinations. This means a lot of Buys and Sells which don't match this sequence can be ignored. I'm confused about the `TypingError` you get, can't see where it could happen.

Comment: Can you post an example this would miss? The typing error is in the first line of the function “global signature unrecognized for type np.object”. Both inputs were float or int when I tested, maybe providing the timing setup would be helpful, and I’ll try and validate again

Comment: I think your solution should be fine in terms of result. For performance, I've updated my question to include my benchmarking code.

Answer (score 4):

By using `cumcount` to find the pair:

```
s=df.groupby('Results').cumcount()
df['Diff']=df.Price.groupby(s).diff().loc[df.Results.isin(['Buy','Sell'])]
df
Out[596]: 
   Index  Results  Price  Diff
0      0      Buy     10   NaN
1      1     Sell     11   1.0
2      2      Buy     12   NaN
3      3  Neutral     13   NaN
4      4      Buy     14   NaN
5      5     Sell     15   3.0
```

Comment: Nice! This solves the readability crisis. But I'm finding this *much* slower than `numba` :(. E.g. on `pd.concat([df]*10**4, ignore_index=True)`, 8.33ms vs 6.44s.

Comment: @jpp I think in pandas vectorised dose not always mean efficient :-)